# Energy consumption

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, estimation, earthquake

If the **yearly** worldwide energy consumption is 80,000 TWh, and a particular earthquake generates 1.6x10^13 Joules of energy.

If we could harness all of the energy from the earthquake, for how long could we power the entire earth?

Comment: Look up the conversion rate from J to kWh. Then do the maths.

Comment: @hdhondt I don’t understand, the question does not mention KWh, only joules and TWh.

Comment: KWh= *kilo* Watts-hour=1,000 Wh. TWh= *tera* Watts-hour=1,000,000,000,000 Wh. The prefixes in most quantities in physics are multiplication by some factor of 1000.

Comment: You should not have to look up *anything*. You should understand what the relationship is between a joule and a watt-hour.

Answer (score 1):

1 watt-second = 1 joule, 1 kilowatt-hour = 3.6 megajoules

As this is under homework you should be able to figure it with this info.